# Using preg_replace on an an array rather than a string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm using the PHP **preg_replace** function on a string called $where:

```
$where = preg_replace( '/data\./', '', $where );
```

However I'd like to achieve the same expression replacement if $where is an array of an unknown size.

Do I have to set up a loop? Or is there a PHP function to help me out?

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Okay, here is my input array:

```
array
  0 => null
  1 => null
  2 => 
    array
      'condition' => 
        array
          'column' => string 'start' (length=5)
          'operator' => string '>=' (length=2)
          'argvalue' => string '2013-11-21 00:00:00' (length=19)
  3 => 
    array
      'condition' => 
        array
          'column' => string 'start' (length=5)
          'operator' => string '<=' (length=2)
          'argvalue' => string '2013-11-21 23:59:59' (length=19)
  4 => null
```

Here is my manipulation:

```
$where = preg_replace('/start\./', 'Alan', $where );
```

And here is my output:

```
array
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string 'Array' (length=5)
  3 => string 'Array' (length=5)
  4 => string '' (length=0)
```

This is returning an Array to String conversion error.

Thanks

Comment: preg_replace is sufficient it also takes array as an first, second argument and third argument

Comment: From the [docs](http://www.php.net/function.preg-replace): __subject__
The string or an array with strings to search and replace. 

If subject is an array, then the search and replace is performed on every entry of subject, and the return value is an array as well.

Comment: RTFM http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: @wisdom: The first argument can be also an array.

Comment: Thanks, I did refer to the docs which is why the result is confusing. Please see the additional code I've added to my original post.

Comment: `preg_replace`  works on an array of strings, not on an array of array. You have to create a recursive fonction that acts on leaves.

Answer (score 1):

PHP docs on the *subject* argument of [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace)

> - **subject**
>
>   The string or an array with strings to search and replace.
>
>   If subject is an array, then the search and replace is performed on every entry of subject, and the return value is an array as well.

Comment: Thanks, I did refer to the docs which is why the result is confusing. Please see the additional code I've added to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$text = array( "editpostiddata" ,"editpodatastcat", "ch114","ch112");

$result = preg_replace(array_fill(0, 4, "/data/i"),'', $text);
print_r($result);
```